# comparing 2 character values in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to compare two char values, to see if the 'value' of one is greater than the other.
My two values are char letter and char str[i].

At first I wrote; `'letter'<'str[i]'`, which didn't work, but when I wrote `letter<str[i]`, it did work.

I don't understand why we need to remove the quotation marks because aren't we comparing the VALUE of the character , and not the character itself...?

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The part `letter < str[i]` should work fine for comparison of `char` values, provided that `letter` is of type `char` and `str` is of type `char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
letter<str[i]
```

This gives the value of char so you don't need quotation

Like

```
char letter = 'a';
```

need quotation during initializing.

`letter` is a variable of type `char` and you can just use the variable to compare value stored in this variable.

Comment: okay, so we ARE comparing the ASCII values of both without the quotations ?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes (`''`) are used to enclose characters. `letters` and `str[i]` are of `char` types which holds character, not a character by themselves. So `'letter'<'str[i]'` is wrong. You just need `letter < str[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Character value *is* the character itself. ' ' is needed to get the value of a specific *symbol*, like 'а'.